# UnityEditor related classes can not be referenced. Why?

Tags: unity, editors, interface

I have two classes. Both of them are placed in the `editor/interface_field` folder.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace editor.interface_field
{
    public class RequiredInterfaceAttribute : PropertyAttribute
    {
        public readonly Type type;

        public RequiredInterfaceAttribute(Type type)
        {
            this.type = type;
        }
    }
}
```

```
    using UnityEditor;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    namespace editor.interface_field
    {
        [CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(RequiredInterfaceAttribute))]
        public class RequireInterfaceDrawer : PropertyDrawer
        {
            public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
            {
                if(property.propertyType == SerializedPropertyType.ObjectReference)
                {
                    var requiredAttribute = this.attribute as RequiredInterfaceAttribute;
    
                    EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);
    
                    property.objectReferenceValue =
                        EditorGUI.ObjectField(position, label, property.objectReferenceValue, requiredAttribute.type, true);
    
                    EditorGUI.EndProperty();
                }
                else
                {
                    var previousColor = GUI.color;
                    GUI.color = Color.red;
    
                    EditorGUI.LabelField(position, label, new GUIContent("Property is not a reference type"));
    
                    GUI.color = previousColor;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have another class.

```
using editor.interface_field;
using UnityEngine;

namespace interface_user.implementations
{
    public interface IInterface {}
    public class InterfaceUser : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField]
        [RequiredInterface(typeof(IInterface))]
        UnityEngine.Object interfaceImplementation;
    }
}
```

The `[RequiredInterface(typeof(IInterface))]` line throws the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'RequiredInterfaceAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS0246)

I can not understand why does not Unity see the `RequiredInterfaceAttribute` class and how could I make it see it.

Comment: Is your other class *not* in an editor folder? Your editor assemblies will not be visible from non-editor code.

Comment: @DMGregory, I just figured it out. So, the best way to do it is to leave all the `*Drawer` classes in the `editor` folder and move the `*Attribute` classes to a separate (non-editor) folder and then reference the `*Attribute` classes from the `*Drawer` classes. This way everything is working. Should I remove my question? I mean yes, you are right the other classes are outside the `editor` folder.

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as #DMGregory pointed out the classes inside the `editor` folder can not be referenced by classes outside of the `editor` folder. But the classes inside the `editor` folder can easily reference classes outside the `editor` folder. Given all that here is how I solved the issue.

I created a folder named `game_editor` and moved the `RequiredInterfaceAttribute` into it. Along the way I changed the namespace from the `editor.interface_field.RequiredInterfaceAttribute` to the `game_editor.interface_field.RequiredInterfaceAttribute` and added a respective `using` to the `RequireInterfaceDrawer`.

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using game_editor.interface_field;

namespace editor.interface_field
{
    [CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(RequiredInterfaceAttribute))]
    public class RequireInterfaceDrawer : PropertyDrawer
    {
        public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
        {
            if(property.propertyType == SerializedPropertyType.ObjectReference)
            {
                var requiredAttribute = this.attribute as RequiredInterfaceAttribute;

                EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

                property.objectReferenceValue =
                    EditorGUI.ObjectField(position, label, property.objectReferenceValue, requiredAttribute.type, true);

                EditorGUI.EndProperty();
            }
            else
            {
                var previousColor = GUI.color;
                GUI.color = Color.red;

                EditorGUI.LabelField(position, label, new GUIContent("Property is not a reference type"));

                GUI.color = previousColor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
    using System;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    namespace game_editor.interface_field
    {
        public class RequiredInterfaceAttribute : PropertyAttribute
        {
            public readonly Type type;
    
            public RequiredInterfaceAttribute(Type type)
            {
                this.type = type;
            }
        }
    }
```